# How to make node title translatable?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have a content type in D8 that requires translation, however at the moment I appear to be only able to translate the individual fields and not the title.

[image: Title says all languages]

The language selector is available on the content type edit page, but there seems to be no way of selecting to translate the title:

[image: Language selector]

Other fields have a checkbox that allows them to be translatable:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The title is set as translatable by default (in the entity definition). Somehow you've disabled translation for this field. You can check the translatable fields for all content types here: /admin/config/regional/content-language

Comment: Ah yes, that's the one! I don't think anyone has actively turned it off, it's a site in alpha build at the moment..! If you post this as an answer, I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title is set as translatable by default (in the entity definition). Somehow you've disabled translation for this field. You can check the translatable fields for content entities here:

```
/admin/config/regional/content-language
```

This includes all fields, also the base fields, which you can't configure in *Manage Fields* of the content type.